# In my PHP Script REMOTE_ADDR gives my true address but using whatsmyip in Google shows my VPN address

Tags: php, iis, networking, server, vpn

I seem to be getting different results when I check my IP address while connected to my VPN and accessing my web server than I get when I do a whatsmyip Google search.

When I dont have my VPN connected (on my laptop in a remote location) and I access my web server, my PHP returns the ip address of the hotspot I am connected to where I am staying and the same address is shown when i google WhatsmyIP.

However, when I connect to my VPN, the Google WhatsmyIP shows my VPN public IP which is whats I expected but no matter what I try, my web server with my PHP script using the server variable of getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') that shows my public IP keeps showing the actual hotspot public IP and NOT the address that my VPN is broadcasting. My web server, if it makes a difference, is Microsoft IIS running on Server 2016 Standard.

My VPN server is running on my work network main server (also the web server) using Server 2016 and its inbuilt remote access services and I am using the built in VPN connection with Windows 10 on my laptop where I am staying.

Normally I would be thrilled that my script shows a users real address however when accessing intranet sites that are restricted to IP addresses on the work LAN, when I use my VPN or if I dont, it still sees me as a remote user and I cant find a way to see me as a local Intranet connected user with a local address of 192.168.1.xxx.

Other posters here and elsewhere have posted the exact opposite and are asking for how to get the true IP of incoming connections but maybe I am missing something but I have the exact OPPOSITE problem.

Does it have something to do with the fact the VPN server and the web server are on the same server and IP address ?  Perhaps the VPN knows the true address being used to connect and it is passing that through to the PHP script through the web server.  If this is the case, is there anything I can do to stop this without moving the VPN server to a different server than the web server I am accessing for its intranet content ?

Comment: Check your VPN config. Those often have options to bypass the VPN for “local” connections, or something similar. Sounds pretty much like this was the case here. _“Perhaps the VPN knows the true address being used to connect and it is passing that through to the PHP script through the web server.”_ - no, I think it is much more likely that your request is circumventing the VPN altogether to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your true IP address is your public IP. IP address on the range:
1. 10.x.x.x ClassA
2. 172.16.x.x Class B
3. 192.168.x.x CLass C

Are private addresses that uses a NAT or PAT to get a real public address(your router address). This private ip addresses are not for public use. You can't route any traffic on the internet to an ip address 192.168.0.2, you can only route those ip inside your network. When you visit your page your having the expected result, your public IP.

hope it helps.

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use classes. You should explain that the Private address ranges are `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` (more than one of the old Class B networks), and `192.168.0.0/16` (more than one of the old Class C networks). Also, PAT is a vendor-specific term for NAPT, which is defined in _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663)_.